# RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to change the link "http://blog.test.com/" to "http://www.test.com/blog/".

I've tried the following code in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^blog.test.com?$ test.com/blog [NC,R=301,L]
```

Did I miss anything? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're using apache, you need to match the host part of the url (e.g. blog.test.com) in a RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.test.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.com/blog/$1  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `sorry...this is not working`: Have seen many of these type of comments here. If you really want to get good answers do provide good explanation of what's not working. For ex: you need to tell which URI didn't work and you also can take a look at your access.log and error.log and post matching lines here.

Comment: now itself it shows blog.test.com. it is not redirected to test.com/blog

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you must replace `http://blog.test.com/whatever_or_empty` to `http://www.test.com/blog/whatever_or_empty` in your HTML hrefs.

`blog.test.com` although a sub domain, is a different URL. i.e. when a RewriteRule does a rewrite to another URL an external redirect will occur. This will reflect in the browser. Be a temporary `redirect(302(the default))` or `permanent redirect(301)`.

So, using url rewriting to change the link `http://blog.test.com/` to `http://www.test.com/blog/` is useless.

---

Although, you can achieve this using [Apache Module mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html).

The Apache Proxy Modules has these:

> - mod_proxy: The core module deals with proxy infrastructure and configuration and managing a proxy request.
> - mod_proxy_http: This handles fetching documents with HTTP and HTTPS.
> - mod_proxy_ftp: This handles fetching documents with FTP.
> - mod_proxy_connect: This handles the CONNECT method for secure (SSL) tunneling.
> - mod_proxy_ajp: This handles the AJP protocol for Tomcat and similar backend servers.
> - mod_proxy_balancer implements clustering and load-balancing over multiple backends.
> - mod_cache, mod_disk_cache, mod_mem_cache: These deal with managing a document cache. To enable caching requires mod_cache and one or both of disk_cache and mem_cache.
> - mod_proxy_html: This rewrites HTML links into a proxy's address space.
> - mod_xml2enc: This supports internationalisation (i18n) on behalf of mod_proxy_html and other markup-filtering modules. space.
> - mod_headers: This modifies HTTP request and response headers.
> - mod_deflate: Negotiates compression with clients and backends.

---

You need at-least `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` modules enabled for the proxy to work:

you should have lines similar to these in your apache's `conf` file:

```
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
```

use this in your **`Virtualhost`** of `http://www.test.com`

```
ProxyPass /blog http://blog.test.com
ProxyPassReverse /blog http://blog.test.com
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy *>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

**Definitions:**

> - [ProxyPass <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass).
> - [ProxyPassReverse <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse).
> - [ProxyRequests <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests).
> - [Proxyvia <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyvia).

---

You can also use a cache with `mod_cache`: `mod_cache`.
For more on caching, refer here: [mod_cache <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cache.html).